# High memory usage when determining mime type using finfo->buffer(), but only with certain text file types?

Tags: php

Is this a bug with how the finfo->buffer method works? I noticed that PHP allocates a significant amount of memory when determining mime type using finfo, and only with certain file types like csv and txt files. Quick sample code below:

```
// Load a 60 MB CSV file
$contents = file_get_contents('file.csv');
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

// Outputs text/plain. Peak memory usage after this is 400+ MB
echo $finfo->buffer($contents);
```

If I try a different file type though, like a large zipped archive for example, memory usage barely changes after the file_get_contents call.

This was tested on PHP 7.2.28

Comment: Seems excessive. But possibly because those text files do not have any discernible header. So the whole thing must be scanned. Just guessing. Doesn't explain the 400+ MB

Comment: @GetSet You might be right about the text files not having headers. I wonder if this is related in any way to this old PHP bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69224

Comment: It looks like it is.

Answer (score 0):

it can be some sort of php or libmagic bug as mentioned here:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79263

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78987

I saw the Issue on a machine with:

> php 7.3.31-1~deb10u1
>
> libmagic 533

but there wasn't any problem on another machine with this config:

> php 7.4.29
>
> libmagic 537

so if you update your software packages the problem should be fixed.

another work around would be using `file()` method.
instead of:

```
$finfo->buffer($contents);
```

saving the content somewhere on the disk, then :

```
$finfo->file($filepath);
```

links:

[libmagic file Issue, on version 5.33](https://bugs.astron.com/view.php?id=146)